# GoRoutine that Returns Two Channels

Tags: function, go

Can someone please help me understand how to interpret the following line of code in the function return - **(_, _ <-chan interface{})**

I understand that the function returns two channels. But I don't understand how it is achieved using the following (_, _ <-chan interface{}). What is the difference if I just swap it out for (<-chan interface{}, <-chan interface{})?

```
tee := func(
    done <-chan interface{},
    in <-chan interface{},
) (_, _ <-chan interface{}) {
    out1 := make(chan interface{})
    out2 := make(chan interface{})

    go func() {
        defer close(out1)
        defer close(out2)

        for val := range orDone(done, in) {
            var out1, out2 = out1, out2
            for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
                select {
                case <-done:
                case out1 <- val:
                    out1 = nil
                case out2 <- val:
                    out2 = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }()
    return out1, out2
}`
```

Comment: No difference. The original author was being "clever" and saving a couple of keystrokes once at the cost of clarity, a poor trade-off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(_, _ <-chan interface{})` is equivalent to `(<-chan interface{}, <-chan interface{})`. There are no differences, except source code length and readability.

1. We start with `(<-chan interface{}, <-chan interface{})` return value types.
2. As return values can have names, one can write `(ch1 <-chan interface{}, ch2 <-chan interface{})` to return same 2 channels.
3. Sequence of arguments (or return values) with same types can omit types for all variables except last one. Hence our return types become: `(ch1, ch2 <-chan interface{})`
4. And since we don't really need the names of return values, we can substitute names with underscore, making them anonymous again: `(_, _ <-chan interface{})`

Voila! Readable pair of channels of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `func` declaration

```
FunctionType   = "func" Signature .
Signature      = Parameters [ Result ] .
Result         = Parameters | Type .
Parameters     = "(" [ ParameterList [ "," ] ] ")" .
ParameterList  = ParameterDecl { "," ParameterDecl } .
ParameterDecl  = [ IdentifierList ] [ "..." ] Type .
```

As you can see, the `Result` is like method's parameters a `Parameters` which in turn boils down to an `IdentifierList`. There comes the blank identifier `_` that can replace every identifier in the `IdentifierList`.

The original author used this together with the "multiple identifiers declared to the same type" syntax to produce - as already mentioned - a strange to read declaration of two return values of the same type.

See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations

You can also implement functions which "delete" parameters by using the blank identifier for them. May come handy, when you don't need the parameter of an interface you implement.

```
func foo(a string, _ int, b string) { ... }
```

The second parameter is not usable.